# Replacing static files that are under heavy read load

Tags: nginx, concurrency, symlink, static-files, fileserver

Let us assume we have a static file server (Nginx + Linux) that serves 10 files. The files are read almost as frequently as the server can process. However, some of the files need to be replaced with new versions, so that the filename and URL address remain unaltered. How to replace the files safely without a fear that some reads fail or become a mix of two versions?

I understand this is a rather basic operating system matter and has something to do with renames, symlinks, and file sizes. However, I failed to find a clear reference or a good discussion and I hope we can build one here.

Comment: A closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186263/how-to-safely-and-transactionally-replace-a-file-on-linux

Answer (score 2):

Use `rsync`. Typically I choose `rsync -av src dst`, but YMMV.

What is terrific about rsync is that, in addition to having essentially zero cost when little or nothing changed, it uses atomic rename. So during file transfer, a ".fooNNNNN" temp file gets bigger and bigger. Once completed, rsync closes the file and renames it on top of "foo". So web clients either see **all of the old, or all of the new file**. Notice that range downloads (say from restart after error) are not atomic, exposing such clients to lossage, especially if bytes were inserted near beginning of file. SHA1 wouldn't validate for such a client, and he would have to restart his download from scratch. BTW, if these are "large" files, tell nginx to use zero-copy `sendfile()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I guess the beef is that renames are atomic in Linux. In my case the new versions are generated by a worker process on the same server, so rsync would probably be an overkill, especially if the files are small. The question did not mention that, though, 'coz I wanted to keep it on general level. Interesting points still!